# vscode custom edtior extension development: No editors associated with document

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a markdown vscode extension based on CustomEditor，and it works as expectation.

But a warning appeared in Console：No editors associated with document: xxx.md

[image]

Source Code： https://github.com/TobiasTao/vscode-md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from https://github.com/CoenraadS/Bracket-Pair-Colorizer-2/blob/6ab0a5656d97b1f86fb9c5b0405072aabd252990/src/documentDecoration.ts#L151.

You can see it also when you "Toggle Developer Tools" and then you get a link like

```
~/.vscode/extensions/coenraads.bracket-pair-colorizer-2-0.1.4/out/src/documentDecoration.js
```

pointing to the culprit. It's surely unrelated to your own extension.

---

There's already an issue: https://github.com/CoenraadS/Bracket-Pair-Colorizer-2/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

In `package.json`:

Change

```
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
```

to

```
  "main": "./dist/extension.js",
```

Comment: I find that the warning appeared in Console perhaps not caused by your extension. I tried the built-in markdown preview, the warning appeared again.